# Project euler 12 python code doesn't run, is it slow or what?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def num_of_divisors(x):
    k=0
    b=x

    while x%2==0:
        x=x//2
        k=k+1
    z=1
    while x!=1:
        for y in range(3,b,2):
            a=0
            while x%y==0:
                x=x//y
                a=a+1
            z=z*(a+1)
    return(z*(k+1))

def triangular(n):
    return(n*(n+1)//2)

for n in range(1,10000):
    jk=triangular(n)
    if num_of_divisors(jk)>500:
        print(triangular(n))
        break
```

the problem is :

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>
> 3: 1,3
>
> 6: 1,2,3,6
>
> 10: 1,2,5,10
>
> 15: 1,3,5,15
>
> 21: 1,3,7,21
>
> 28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

The problem is to find the first triangular number with more than 500 divisors.

I separately checked the num_of_divisors() function , it works correctly . I also checked num_of_divisors(76576500), it returns 576 correctly.

The triangular function also works correctly.

But the above program doesn't run . So the problem is in the loop. But what is it? I mean , it runs but nothing happens. I thought it might be very slow so I replaced 500 with 1  , yet it doesn't work! What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `while x!=1` is putting you in an infinite loop when the number is a prime number. That's because only the number itself can divide it, and your `range` does not get that number.

For example, when `x` is 3, 5, or 7 (all primes) -

```
In [12]: list(range(3,3,2))
Out[12]: []

In [14]: list(range(3,5,2))
Out[14]: [3]

In [15]: list(range(3,7,2))
Out[15]: [3, 5]
```

The only way to break out of the `while x!=1` loop is when `x==1`, but that does not happen because `x` never gets divided by itself. You can avoid that by letting your `range` go further.

Comment: Aah I fixed it and now it works for small numbers like 60 , but 500 is too much and it doesn't print...

Comment: I assume you've fixed this by adding one to your range.  You might now need to look at your algorithm, The 1st triangular number with 500 divisors may be fairly large (hint, *it is*) and your algorithm might take a long time to find it...  It will eventually, though, as it does find the correct numbers...